# Hide/Remove side bar: Cases - Recently Viewed (Salesforce Lightning)

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

In Salesforce lightning - is there a way to hide/remove certain elements? Like in this example the left side bar shows recently viewed cases. How can I hide/remove the left side bar Recently Viewed Cases?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an arrow for this "Split view mode" which allows to hide the left side.
[image]